# Is there a data type and enter number more than 10 billion in it and then make an operation on it like *

Tags: c++, overflow

My program is to sum an arithmetic sequence from 1 to n like
-1 2 -3 4 -5 6 -7 etc...
But
n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^15).
And when I execute this program, I am faced with that the sum variable is overflowing although I use data type `long long`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long n;

    cin >>n;

    if (n%2!=0)
    {      
        long long sump = ((n-1)/4.0) * (2+(n-1));
        long long sumn = ((n+1)/4.0) * (-1-n);
        long long sum = sump + sumn;
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
     else
    {         
        long long sump = ((n)/4.0) * (2+(n));
        long long sumn = ((n)/4.0) * (-1-(n-1));
        long long sum = sump + sumn;
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not in c++ standard. You can check out boost::multiprecision

Comment: Or you use a trick that doesn't sum all the numbers in the sequence and instead uses a simple one-shot formula to compute the sum without ever overflowing. For example -1 +2 = 1 -3 + 4 = 1 -5 + 6 = 1... Get it?

Comment: *"I am faced with that the sum variable is overflowing although I use data type `long long`"* -- well, yeah. You could be (twice) adding on the order of 10^15 numbers whose magnitudes go up to 10^15. Ballpark estimate is that the sum is on the order of 10^(15+15). Each sum will be strictly less than that, but that's the rough order of magnitude. If you figure each 10^3 factor corresponds to about 10 bits, you are looking at around 100 bits to store these sums. Again, strictly less will be needed, but still well over 64. Your approach is not the one desired by the "challenge" site.

Comment: Check out https://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you see such big numbers in questions, then most often you cannot solve that by brute force, running big loops and the like.

You need to find an analytical or mathematical solution.

Even, if you do not know the solution, you may look at example values.

If you look at your series, then you can see something like the below:

```
Index   Sign    Series      Sum
0       1       0           0
1      -1      -1          -1
2       1       2           1
3      -1      -3          -2
4       1       4           2
5      -1      -5          -3
6       1       6           3
7      -1      -7          -4
8       1       8           4
9      -1      -9          -5
10      1      10           5
```

As you can see,

- if n is even, then the result is n/2
- if n is odd then the result is -((n/2)+1)

And this can be easily implemented . . .